# Percentile Ranks in R of specific columns, adding the PR values to end of the DF in new columns for each column calculated

Tags: r

I have a DF from a CSV with 31 columns, I am trying to obtain the percentile ranks of columns 10-31 & then apply those new PR values as columns on the end of the DF, Shortened example of dataset below BOLD signifies columns I wish to Percentile rank(Rstudio user)

ID.  Age.  Type.        Value_Added   (NEW COLUMN TO BE - PR_Value_Added)

1. 20. SH           87.9              ?
2. 30. FH           43.9              ?
3. 40. WG           23.2              ?

Comment: So in this example what would be the correct result using your notion of what a "percentile rank" would be?  (And do learn to post examples that can be cut and pasted)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).